# PHP Service Layer and json encoding

Tags: rest, model-view-controller, service-layer

I have a REST controller whice should return a list of companies in json format. The companies are fetched by a service. Where should i encode the result into json format? I tought of an encoder class, but where should i inject that?

Comment: In the same place where you would turn the list of companies in a HTML list: template. That's what view instance are using to assemble the response.

Answer (score -1):

PHP Offers JSON encoding / decoding functionality built in:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

```
$json_result = json_encode($array_to_be_encoded);
```

Comment: Yep, i know that, but my service returns an object instead of an array. My question is where i should encode the result. In the service or in the controller?

Comment: I would imagine the Service layer would be best suited for JSON encoding.